# Jvectormap clear previous data from map in AJAX load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqvmap

I'm using jvectormap and I noticed that map data is actually accumulating on each call. For example, if there was 1 from spain, and on next load there is 1 from Italy, on 2nd map load it show 1 Spain and 1 Italy and so on.

```
var singlemap = $('#singleMap').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_en',
    backgroundColor: null,
    color: '#eaeaea',
    hoverOpacity: 0.7,
    //selectedColor: '#666666',
    enableZoom: false,
    showTooltip: true,
    values: {

    },
    scaleColors: ['#6FC6EA', '#0A4D70'],
    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
});
```

I'm using setValues as below for reloading data, how can I clear data from map before showing new?

```
singlemap.setValues(mapstringJSON);
```

Comment: anyone, any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution, on each setvalue i empty the html in div and set singlemap to null and then initialize the map again, before seting values.

```
$('#singleMap').empty();
singlemap = null;
singlemap = $('#singleMap').vectorMap({
  map: 'world_en',
  backgroundColor: null,
  color: '#eaeaea',
  hoverOpacity: 0.7,
  enableZoom: false,
  showTooltip: true,
  values: {},
  scaleColors: ['#6FC6EA', '#0A4D70'],
  normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
});
singlemap.setValues(mapstringJSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

I change :

```
$('#singleMap').empty();
```

to:

```
$('.singleMap').empty();
```

it works.
it's because my `singleMap` is not declared as an ID

```
<div class="singleMap" style="width: 800px; height: 500px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
`$('#singleMap')` refers to an element having 'singleMap' as id, like

```
<div id="singleMap"></div>
```

`$('.singleMap')` refers to an element having 'singleMap' as a class, like

```
<div class="singleMap"></div>
```